React Native Build Failed. Showing Gradlew Issue
pp:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,arm64-v8a exited with non-zero code: 1

I'm using React Native Expo and CLI. Using a prebuild boilerplate ignite to make my work easy.
Using Gradle 8.6 and jDK 17.0.12. My android studio is updated.
When ever I try to run: npm run andorid -- it shows build failed.
What could be the possible reasons for facing this issue?
I'm using VScode along with Android studio. and using https://docs.infinite.red/ignite-cli/
I'm expecting my code to be built and run smoothly on my Android emulator
enter image description here
